# Can I use a GeForce GTX 750 Ti graphics card in Dell Precision T1700?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I want to buy a [Geforce 750 Ti](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti) for my [Dell Precision T1700](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-t1700-workstation/pd). But I'm worried if the power supply is sufficient. The Dell Precision T1700  has a "365W 90% efficient (80 Plus® Gold Certified)" PSU and Dell says that it supports

> one PCI Express® x16 Gen 3 graphic card up to 150W (total for graphics)

Does that mean I can use a graphics card as long as its maximum power is less than 150 W? Like [this one](http://www.inno3d.com/product/gtx750ti.html), its "Maximum Graphics Card Power" is only 60 W, but its "Minimum System Power Requirement" is 400 W which is more than 365 W. So can I use it?

Comment: You will be fine the 750 is a 60w card and gets power from the PCIE slot.

Comment: @Kyle But what if a card needs additional power connector but still is 60 W?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, Nvidia has stated these cards will be bus powered and not require additional connectors.

Comment: @Kyle I mean some non-reference graphics cards may require a 6-pin power connector, like this one: http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=02G-P4-3757-KR.

Comment: @EFanZh - You asked about a specific card.  If it requires no additional PCI-E power cables then its simply powered by the PCI-E bus.  Shoot for that the 750 product line is exactly that ( possible exception is an overclocked model )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer manufacturer will have more specific information as to the available power than the GPU manufacturer.  To be safe, the GPU manufacturers when they give a "Minimum System Power Requirement" usually over-estimate a bit.  If Dell says you have up to 150W for graphics use, than any GPU that is a 150W or under card should work.  Trust your manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

If your PSU doesn't supply enough power then your computer may have subtle problems as a result like distorted graphics, computer turning off, and poor fan speed which may cause overheating. I speak from experience with my own computer when I started building my first one. When upgrading a graphics card I would use 500 W PSU as a minimum. Some of those graphics cards have special power needs like a 6 pin connector (some require an 8 pin connection) from the PSU and only PSUs with higher Watts (500 and up) provide that from what I've seen. Before you buy always check to see what connection and power the graphics card needs and what connections and power your PSU provides. Also pay attention to how much voltage is needed on those PSU rails too.

What you are saying means that the computer and graphics card will run on that PSU, but unless you meet that minimum system requirement there will likely be issues like I described AND a good graphics card needs a special connector from the PSU for that extra power.